# PowerApps -If LookUp() is NULL with external data source - Power APPS BREAKS

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerapps

I have a PowerBi report with several data sources, SQL query and Excel connector.

The SQL data data on our Products whereas the Excel is living data on salesperson notes on said products.

The PowerBI has a PowerApp visualization. The Power App has 3 pages:

**Page 1** is landing page that Gallery displays data from PowerBi

**Page 2** is a form edit page to edit notes in the Excel spreadsheet that we know exists because we saw those notes in the PowerBi report

**Page 3** is a form edit page to add new notes in the Excel spreadsheet that we know we have to add because we did not see them in the PBI report

On **Page 1** are two buttons, "Edit" and "New" that navigates to the proper page.

**Now here the WTF moment**

*IF* the Product has notes and the user clicks on the *NEW* button, then PowerApps adds the line to the Excel spreadsheet, causing duplicates and thus the PowerBi report cannot refresh. It breaks.

*If* the Product does not have notes and the user clicks on the *EDIT* button then PowerApps does a `LookUp(ExcelSpreadsheet, Column=Gallery1.Selected.PowerBiValue` which results in a **NULL** value and thus breaks with a dreaded **server response: expression "... eq null" is not supported.**

*If* I try to add the 'IsEmpty()' to preemptive counter it, the 'Lookup()' is run first thus **breaking** before it gets to the 'IsEmpty()', same goes with 'IsBlank', 'IsBlankOrError', and 'IsError'.

I have Googled the living %(#$* out of this and there seems to be nothing on it, as this is in direct relation to 'LookUp' on the Excel Spreadsheet **not** a dropdown or in app text box that other people have issues with. How is it that you can't even use the error handler 'IsError()' as it breaks before the handler can even have a chance to do anything.

If I use `LookUp(ExcelSpreadsheet, Column=Gallery1.Selected.PowerBiValue)` in ***any way, shape, or form, with or without If clauses,*** because it will eventually produce a **NULL** result, Power Apps **breaks**

**How do I read null values from a data source?**

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

Since the "living data" Excel spreadsheet is also in the PowerBi report, I have PowerBi *send* the living data values along with the SQL queried product values to the PowerApp.  Since the NULL is now a sent from PowerBi instead of queried from Excel within PowerApps, I can have 1 button that's OnSelect property reads:

```
IF(IsBlankorError(Gallery1.Selected.LivingDataNotes),Navigate(NewNotes),Navigate(EditNotes)
```